# Rails 4: Model Logic - (Limited Associations)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, controller

Is there a way to use a similar command to `.where()` in the Model?

In my instance I want to loop through items but I want to check for a database value first:

User Model:

```
has_many :purchases
has_many :purchasedtools, through: :purchases, source: :tool #only where "status: "Completed"!
```

Purchase Model:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :tool
```

Tool Model:

```
belongs_to :user
has_many :purchases
```

Tools Controller:

```
def index
    @boughttools = current_user.purchasedtools
end
```

Tool Index View:

```
- @boughttools.limit(4).each do |tool|
```

I expect something like: `@boughttools = current_user.purchases.where(status: "Completed", user_id: current_user.id)`.
The only difference is that I need `purchasedtools` instead of `purchases` because I want the actual Tools as source.
Fortunately I can't just change this as is because the db values I check are on the `purchase` table and not on the `tool` table.
Thanks in advance for each answer! Please tell me if you need additional information.

Comment: Can you add something example what you expect?

Comment: I expect something like: `@boughttools = current_user.purchases.where(status: "Completed", user_id: current_user.id)` The only difference is that I need `purchasedtools` instead of `purchases` because I want the actual Tools as source. Fortunately I can't just change this as is because the db values I check are on the `purchase` table and not on the `tool` table. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Why don't you start by creating a proper example? Include the model classes above and what the desired result is.

Comment: do you look for conditional has_many or what? `has_many :purchasedtools, through: :purchases, source: :tool, -> { where(status: 'Completed') }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a scope to an association you simply pass a lambda or proc to the association macro:

```
class User
  has_many :purchases
  has_many :completed_purchases, ->{ where(status: 'Complete') },
    class_name: 'Purchase'
  has_many :purchased_tools
    through: :completed_purchases
    source: :tool
end
```

### Added

A simpler way to do this as noticed by the OP would just be to specify that the condition applies to the join table:

```
  has_many :purchased_tools, -> { where(purchases: {status: "Completed"} ) }
    through: :completed_purchases
    source: :tool
```

See [Scopes for has_many](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: PS. stick to the `snake_case` naming scheme when naming variables, methods and associations.

Comment: I put that scope on `purchases`, cause it checks the Purchase DB Table and that gives me nothing. I checked in my Console, that there is an item which should get displayed indeed.

Comment: I edited my answer - if you instead add a scoped relationship between user and purchase and use that to join though.

Comment: That works great: `has_many :purchased_tools, ->{ where(purchases: {status: "Completed"}) }, through: :purchases, source: :tool` Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 3):

As I suggested in my comment, you might be looking for a conditional association:

```
has_many :purchasedtools,
         -> { where(status: 'Completed') }
         through:    :purchases,
         source:     :tool
```

Check out [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) for more info on associations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `joins`

```
Purchase.joins(:tool).where(tools: {user_id: current_user.id}, purchases: {status: 'Completed'})
```

Comment: This does not even attempt to answer the question. He is asking about how to set conditions from within the model class.

Comment: He just want get all purchases associated with tools and user ... Applause for you :)